# Can I set variables based on command arguments in a Shell script?

Tags: shell, sh

My goal is to make a shell script that I can run that will generate a static HTML page and I would like to change some of the data in the file, like some text or a class name and I would like to get those variables from a command line argument, like this:

```sh
sh createfile.sh --title "Example" --author "Example"
```

Can you even handle command arguments with a shell script?

Comment: Yes, of course you can handle command line arguments.  But for your use case, it might be easier to just do `title=Example author=Example sh createfile.sh`.   (Assuming you're not using a shell from the `csh` family).  That will make `$title` and `$author` available in the script.

Comment: getopts is another option that can be used

Answer (score 0):

There are a *lot* of ways to parse command line arguments in a script.  The most basic is just to reference them via `$1`, `$2`, etc.  But for your use case, it's probably easier to not bother.  Just do something like:

```
$ cat createfile.sh 
#!/bin/sh

cat << EOF

${title?}

Written by ${author?}
EOF
$ author=doug title='my document' sh createfile.sh 

my document

Written by doug
```

There certainly are reasons to avoid using the environment this way, but if you want to pass the value as parameters there's no reason to enforce using `--` as an indicator.  Just do:

```
#!/bin/sh

for x; do
        if ! test "$x" = "${x#*=}"; then
                eval "$x"
        fi
done

cat << EOF

${title?}

Written by ${author?}
EOF
$ sh createfile.sh author=foo title=bar

bar

Written by foo
```

By avoiding the environment, you prevent accidentally grabbing unexpected values.  Also, this will work if you are using one of the shells from the `csh` family.  This is certainly not robust, and any use of `eval` is suspect, but these are 2 reasonably useful techniques.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to fix my problem.